# Text column and icon alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the text in my column, Maybe its the way the whole thing is setup or maybe its bootstrap itself, The code is horrible but tips are welcome.
Anyway, The col-md-2 text is out of alignment as you can see in the picture below. I believe its supposed to stay in its column? How can I fix this

[image]

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f4737361cc.js"></script>
<div class="container profile-container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 pb-5">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <h2>Titel van de post</h2>
              <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <img src="img/foto.jpg" alt="" width="92" class="rounded-circle pb-3">
              <p class="m-0"><b>Rainier laan</b></p>
              <p class="m-0">Programmeur/Webdeisgnerasdddddddddddddddddddd</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad amet distinctio eos error eveniet ex mollitia non praesentium saepe! Nemo quas quos ullam. Consectetur distinctio ipsa ipsam non quia, recusandae! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet dolorum mollitia odit porro provident? Consectetur cumque dolores earum error ipsa ipsum molestiae necessitatibus numquam odit provident quis, quos, repudiandae rerum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet fuga, modi. Adipisci aliquid beatae consequuntur distinctio dolorem error, eum explicabo maiores minus officia placeat porro ratione reiciendis sit ullam voluptatem.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
              Tags: <span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span> <span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span> <span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-10 pt-4">
              <a href=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></a>1
              <a href=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></a> 2
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, Is there a way to align the thumbs icons better? Also, I'm trying to make them able to have a loop that if the person clicks on it, It goes +1. Right now I can't do that because of the way its build. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure you have a good question on there, but its really unclear. Is your problem with the overflowing text? Or your thumb icons? Or this "loop" that you mention? They are 3 separate questions....

Comment: Its both but the text is now fixed. Sorry, I'm not English. I only need to fix the thumb icons now, I need to make then suitable for a jquery loop but I don't know how

Comment: Your English isn't the problem, its the fact that you are looking for help with many issues in the same question. Questions should be a about one specific coding-related issue. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/

This CSS will fix the issue where the text is spilling outside the div on long words.

```
p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! That worked! Haven't figured it could be that simple, Also do you know how to align the icons better and make then suitable for a query loop?